# Android: Splash Screen Implementation Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-styles

I am trying to implement a splash screen before the MainActivity but cannot get it working. I followed the instructions found here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/. Currently nothing appears but a black delayed screen. Please tell me where I went wrong. Thanks.

### Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

### background_splash.xml

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
        </item>
```

### styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
```

### Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: Before you call  Intent intent .. give it some time to display a splash like 2/3 seconds

Comment: Yes, I will try that.

Comment: `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Your Intent
            }
        }, 2000);`

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. `background_splash.xml` is not showing at all.  Do you know why it might not be showing?

Comment: also make sure that other activity WelcomeActivity have a proper theme or it will inherit from your main app theme  which is `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"`

Comment: Yep, it has a proper theme.

Comment: Ok, silly, silly me. `Layer list` was in the wrong place therefore it was not overlaying the default theme. It is all working now.

Comment: Note that you have an upvote option.Accept an answer only if it helps for your question by doing that  you help other people who gets the same problem to solve the problem.!! Accepting an answer like `Uninstall & install the app again` might not be the best option

Comment: Yes, his code helped me figure out the problem.

Comment: helping and answering is two different things.Answer is not only for you.you cant even delete a post which has answers thats because its for other people who seek for a particular problem

Comment: Thanks for info. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, Uninstall & install the app again, you will get the splash screen.
The problem is due to the instant run in Android Studio

To test, give a delay before starting the new activity:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    startActivity();
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Give a delay to check

Comment: Ok, I think I might know where the problem is. The background color is not properly showing.

Comment: This isn't the exact answer but I'll accept it since it helped diagnose the root of the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` add 
`setContentView(R.layout.layout_name.xml);`

Comment: he is not asking for setContentView